# Change display name and voice

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on Dialogflow. Is there is any way to programmatically access invocation on Action on Google. I am trying to change the voice and display name of the google assistant from my code. Is this possible ?

**Console Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When using Dialogflow, there is no way to programmatically change the invocation name and voice of the Action.

If, on the other hand, you were to use Actions Builder to build your action, you could change the Actions SDK [LocalizedSettings](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/LocalizedSettings) for both the `displayName` and `voice` fields in a YAML file and upload that programmatically.